# Как спросить у HTTP сервера о существовании файла без скачивания?

Tags: http, vb.net

Каким образом можно быстро опросить HTTP сервер о существовании файла `jpg`, так чтобы не скачивать файл. Надо проверить существование порядка 2 000 000 `jpg` файлов, а потом уже скачивать только те что есть.

Comment: Сделать HEAD запрос (если сервер нормальный, он поддерживает даный запрос, плюс если файлы не "фантомные" т.е. не автогенерируемые)

Comment: файлы не фантомные, они лежат в определенной папке.

Comment: Вот один из примеров HEAD запроса http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655302/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-vbscript

Comment: думаю `httpwebrequest` использовать, но пока не нашел вариант с ним

Comment: я вижу там код `VBA` это как бы не `VB.NET`

Comment: Да тут даже HEAD не нужен, скорее всего. Можно сделать обычный GET, проверить существование можно по коду ответа: если 200, сохранять результат в файл, если 404, сохранять "вникуда". В отличие от HEAD, для существующего файла потребуется один запрос (а не два), но для несуществующих сервер ещё пришлёт в теле ответа страничку "Не найдено", обычно небольшого размера.